# 2006 VW Jetta Diesel won't warm up

Tags: vw, cooling-system, heater

A couple of years ago the VW (2006 Jetta) quit warming up.

No heat, no defrost, temperature gauge reads cold!

I changed thermostat and tested both 'stats at the same time. Both opened right at 195 °F.

TDI Forum has not been much help. Only "cure" that they recommended was to stuff the grill with foam pipe insulation or otherwise block the radiator. This helps but is definitely NOT a cure.

The engine also runs cold in the summer - it runs fine without blockage, but running cold is not good for any engine!

Any ideas? Thank heaven for seat heaters!

Comment: This might help: http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/23490/10905

Comment: Can you update your question and explain what evidence you have that it is running cold.  e.g. Heater is cold, dash gauge shows cold, OBDII parameters show its cold, measured temperature of coolant, etc?

Comment: Haven't solved it yet. Suspect the thermostat housing to be leaking inside.

Comment: What year/model is your VW? Which TDI engine? (Jetta would be a 4-cyl ... Toureg could be a W-10.) I don't believe we could do much more than guess with an answer here without more information.

Comment: make/model/year?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Engine never warms up (actually: it cools down) at highway speeds](http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/1991/engine-never-warms-up-actually-it-cools-down-at-highway-speeds)